# Pointer alignment and aliasing

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, strict-aliasing

I have seen quite a few of following code (abstract example):

```
char* byteBlockPtr;

long* alignedPtr = NULL;

/* ... */

/* aligning pointer by long boundary */
while (!ALIGNED(byteBlockPtr))
{
  byteBlockPtr++;
}

alignedPtr = (long*)byteBlockPtr;

/* ... */

/* do stuff with memory */
alignedPtr++; /* go to next block */

/* ... */
```

And this is quite understandable with the reason being that casting from char pointer to a more strict pointer type (in this case pointer to long) requires that the alignment is the same.

Does the same apply to void pointers?

Are there any general rules that one must follow in order not to break the alignment of pointers if, say, one is writing his own memset for example?

What is the connection between pointer aliasing and alignment if any in regards to char and void pointers as well as others? If for example void pointer is implicitly converted to any other pointer type as per standard, does this mean that it is guaranteed that alignment requirements are met as well?

---

P.S. Sorry in advance for more than 1 question, but apparently there is a gap in my knowledge, and I have no idea how to narrow it down.

Comment: `ALIGNED` is not standard. Use standard ways to check the alignment. If that is some custom macro, show it. (Sidenote: the name is choosen badly, as it is not clear which alignment it checks).

Comment: @Olaf, like I said, it's an abstract example. It just checks if a pointer is alingned to a long boundary. I doubt that it's particular implementation is critical to the questions at hand, but if you think otherwise, I'll update the post.

Comment: Did you read the assorted posts on on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=strict+aliasing ?

Comment: AFAIK `char *` and `void *` have the same internal representation, and if you convert from `void *` to an invalid `T *`, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @melpomene Why? Merely assigning it for the first time shouldn't be UB. Reading it afterwards yes. Could you argue about that? Please use standard citation or a good link, with arguments.

Comment: @2501 I can't, which is why I didn't post it as an answer.

Comment: @melpomene How can you assert something you're not sure about/ don't know?

Comment: @2501 1. Like this: There is no extraterrestrial life.  2. I didn't say anything about not being sure or not knowing.  3. I qualified my comment with "AFAIK".

Comment: AFAIK is completely without meaning and you do not get of the hook for using it. Anything someone says is automatically qualified as as far as they know, otherwise they could not have spoken/written the information. You should have been honest and write: I don't know enough about the subject to provide assertion about a it. If you by AFAIK meant really meant that you simply don't know the topic, you actually wrote this: *Ignore the next statement if you want reliable information; statement.* Either way it's useless.

Comment: @2501: It would be legal for an implementation to use different representations for `char*` and `void*`; such a thing might even make sense on an implementation where a pointer to an object is regarded as identifying the last byte rather than the first.  On such a platform, if `char` is 8 bits, converting a `char*` to a `uint32_t*` might entail adding three (since the hardware address of the last byte of a `uint32_t` would be three bytes after that of the last (only) byte of a `uint8_t` with the same starting address.  If `void` is considered to be zero bytes, a `void*` should...

Comment: ...hold a physical address one below a `uint8_t*`.  Even if there may be hardware platforms where such designs would make sense, on the vast majority of hardware platforms (including every general-purpose reprogrammable microcomputer that has ever been mass produced) pointers to objects of all types use the same representation (pointers to functions may use different representations; it's too bad the Standard doesn't have an optional "pointer to any kind of data pointer" type, since it would be useful on the 99.999% of platforms that could readily support it.

Comment: @supercat: I'd be careful with such statements. Or do you know all most all MCUs ever produced and in mass production? It is one of the reasons for C being still used so widely that it does not put too much restrictions on the platform architecture. And youi might do some research about the i432.

Comment: @Olaf: I didn't say microprocessors, since there have certainly been some special-purpose microprocessors with rather interesting designs.  Nor did I say that all pointers had the same representation, since some platforms including the venerable 8086 sported two-byte "near" pointers and four-byte "far" pointers.  My statement was about general-purpose reprogrammable microcomputers, and fact that pointer representation was independent of the *target* type.  I don't know if any general-purpose reprogrammable microcomputers based on the i432 were mass-produced, but...

Comment: ...even if there were I see nothing in the Wiki about it that would suggest that a pointer to any kind of data object would hold anything other than the address of the first byte thereof.

Comment: The 8086 far/near pointers (there were/are other architectures with such - well - "optimisations") are strictly more problermatic with respect to the standard. And the i432 was more of an extreme. Although I really think some of its techniques could nowadays be implemented with true benefit (it might have been just too ambitious for the 80ies). After all, it sometimes looks as if the CPU designers have problem what to do with all the transistors available:-)

Comment: @Olaf: The only "problems" I see with standards compliance on the 8086 would be the widespread use of `near` and `far` as reserved words rather than `__near` and `__far`.  Many platforms required special implementation-specific keywords (e.g. `pascal` or `__pascal`) when calling certain external APIs, and code which didn't need to call external APIs wouldn't need to bother with `near` and `far` either (though judicious use of those keywords could facilitate major performance improvements).  I think the fundamental issue is that C, like many microcomputer languages, used to be defined...

Comment: ...more by precedent than by specification, and many behaviors were well-established on the subset of platforms with silent-wraparound two's-complement hardware and linear pointer addressing.  While people today would regard anything not mandated by the Standard as an "extension" that didn't really exist if not documented, the failure of the Standard to list them in Annex J.5 despite acknowledging that the majority of then-current implementations implemented silent wraparound on overflow would argue that such things weren't viewed as "extensions".

Answer (score 6):

The C Standard allows obtuse implementations to do anything they want if an object of any type is modified using a pointer of any type other than the specific ones listed in the Standard, regardless of whether the compiler would have reason to expect that the object is being modified.  It doesn't matter whether the pointers would be properly aligned or not.  According to the rationale, the rule exists so that given code like:

```
float f;
void hey(int *p)
{
  f=1.0f;
  *p=6;
  f+=1.0f;
}
```

a compiler won't have to pessimistically assume that `p` might hold the address of `f` and thus write `f` before the pointer assignment and read it afterward.  In a case like that the compiler would have no reason to expect that a write to `p` would affect `f`, and thus no reason to expect that the redundant store and load would serve any purpose.

While there's no evidence that the authors of the Standard intended that compiler writers should be so obtuse as to ignore situations where aliasing is obvious, some compiler writers, including those involved with gcc, interpret the lack of a mandate as an indication that they should ignore obvious aliasing when doing so will facilitate more "efficient" code, without regard for whether the code in question will actually be useful.

On any platform which defines a means of checking whether a pointer is suitably aligned for a given type, converting the pointer to char*, incrementing it unless or until it is suitably aligned, and then converting it to that other type will yield a pointer to that other type.  Unfortunately, while C11 defines a standard means of ensuring that an object of one type is located in a fashion meeting the alignment requirements of another, it does not define a standard means by which code can make use of such alignment without running afoul of aliasing issues.

If code only has to run on non-obtuse compilers, I would suggest that casting from one type to another and accessing as the latter type should be reliable provided that operations using the new type are done with a pointer that was cast *from the old type* to the new type after the last access using the old type, and all operations using the cast pointer are done before the next access using the old type.  Most code which uses "chunking optimizations" fits that pattern, and it's an easy pattern for compilers to support without needing to make excessively-pessimistic assumptions (if code casts a pointer from type T1* to T2* and then writes to it, an assumption that such an operation is likely to affect an object of type T1 may be pessimistic, but in most cases it will also be *correct*).

Unfortunately, because the Standard has yet to mandate compiler recognition of aliasing even in cases where it's obvious, and the authors of gcc show no interest in such recognition absent a mandate, there's no way to safely use chunking optimizations in gcc without either using non-standard gcc-specific extensions or else using the `-fno-strict-aliasing` flag.  Getting good performance while using that flag will require learning to use the `restrict` qualifier, but using chunking to speed up hot loops and using `restrict` to minimize the performance impact of `-fno-strict-aliasing` seems like a better approach than using slow non-chunked loops.  Note also that gcc will often process code which uses chunking optimizations correctly with or without the flag, but the authors of gcc consider any correct behavior when such code is compiled without the flag as "accidental" and have no aversion to "fixing" [i.e. breaking] such code without warning.

BTW, if one wants to use chunking optimizations in fully-conformant fashion, the only ways to accomplish that are (1) use byte-oriented code and hope the optimizer somehow figures out how to replace it with a chunked version, or (2) use memcpy/memmove to load word-sized variables from other storage and hope the optimizer manages to replace them with sane code.  For example, if one has a 64-bit aligned pointer to a bunch of uint16_t values and wishes to compute the ones' complement of them, one could use:

```
void flip_quad16s(uint16_t *p, int num_quads)
{
  uint64_t *pp = (uint64_t*)p;
  union {
    uint64_t dw;
    uint16_t hw[4];
  } u;
  for (int i=0; i<num_quads; i++)
  {
    memcpy(u.hw, pp, 8);
    u.dw = ~u.dw;
    /* Note that if p actually identifies something which has no declared
       type but will be used as uint16_t, we must make sure that memcpy
       uses that as a source type */
    memcpy(pp++, u.hw, 8);
  }
}
```

Of course, that will require the compiler to presume that p might alias
anything of any type, which may prevent even a perfect optimizing compiler
from achieving result as good as was a non-obtuse compiler could have
achieved with code that took a uint16_t, cast it to uint64_t, and then
worked with that, e.g.

```
void flip_quad16s(uint16_t *p, int num_quads)
{
  uint64_t *pp = (uint64_t*)p;
  for (int i=0; i<num_quads; i++)
    pp[i] = ~pp[i];
}
```

It should be much easier for a sane compiler to turn the latter function into
optimal code that will invert a bunch of uint16_t values than for any compiler
to do likewise with the former function, especially if it's called within a
loop that makes use of other types, since the use of memcpy would force a
compiler to acknowledge potential aliasing of all types, rather than just
uint16_t and uint64_t.

Comment: Thank you very much for a detailed answer. So if I understood you correctly, you believe, that incrementing pointer to char (full chain would look like this: `void pointer arg -> char pointer mem iterator -> align -> long ptr -> chunk opt-n`) up until it's suitably aligned **is the only proper way to go**, unlike downstraight assignment (`void ptr arg -> long ptr -> chunk opt-n`). Correct?

Comment: If an implementation suitably defines conversions between pointer types and uintptr_t, then processing the pointer numerically and then converting it to a suitable type may be a good way to go unless the next version of the C Standard breaks it by adding the concept of "provenance" to uintptr_t [IMHO an absurd thing to do, since the most common reason for converting pointers to integers is to bypass the type system when accessing machine storage].  If one doesn't handle the alignment via uintptr_t, conversion to char* is probably best if the underlying data may be of types with...

Comment: ...arbitrary alignment.  If a pointer is known to identify aligned objects of type `uint16_t` but one wants to use type `uint32_t` or `uint64_t` to access them, then I'd suggest accepting working with `uint16_t*` until things are aligned, and then casting to `uint32_t*` or `uint64_t*`.

Comment: "The C Standard allows obtuse implementations to do anything they want ..." - No. Violating effective type rule is undefined behaviour. Which is no allowance.

Comment: @supercat So basically if one wants to implement some chunk optimization, he has to align a pointer to a chunk manually? And direct usage after assingment as an alternative is disallowed?

Comment: @Olaf: So are you saying obtuse implementations *aren't* allowed to do anything they want?  Since the authors of the standard acknowledge elsewhere (in the section on implementation limits) that it's possible for an obtuse implementation to be simultaneously compliant and useless, the fact that doing something wouldn't make an implementation non-compliant does not mean that such action wouldn't severely degrade its usefulness.

Comment: @VoidWalker: See my edit.  Some compilers may optimize memcpy() well enough that despite all the memcpy() operations the generated code would come out being similar to the form using direct assignment (though using memcpy may block some otherwise-useful optimizations in the caller), but on others the code would end up more than an order of magnitude slower than it should be.  Some proponents of obtuse aliasing behavior think memcpy is the right approach; others say the code should be written in assembly language.  I'm not sure why they don't accept the idea that implementations that aren't...

Comment: ...obtuse should recognize that if code casts a T* to a U* and accesses that that U* before the next usage of a T*, it should be presumed capable of modifying a T*.

Comment: @supercat: Hmm, on second thought, you might mean the same as I do. To clarify: Once you invoke undefined behaviour, you are beyond the standard. That does not imply the standard allows this behaviour, it just does not define it. Maybe that is a bit misty, but allowing and not defining are two very different terms imo.

Comment: @Olaf: If code invokes Undefined Behavior, nothing an implementation could do would make it non-compliant.  Since the only "power" the Standard has over any implementation is to say that it is or isn't compliant, that means the Standard would "allow" a compliant implementation to do anything (and non-compliant implementations are allowed to do anything whether or not code invokes UB).  The point that hyper-modern compiler writers miss is that before the Standard was written many implementations define behaviors in places where the Standard wouldn't require it but they could do so cheaply, ...

Comment: ...and the authors of the Standard never intended to discourage that.  There are some hardware platforms where an overflow that occurs while adding two registers could have unpredictable effects that might depend upon things like external circuitry the compiler knows nothing about.  Requiring a compiler for such a platform to generate code that behaves predictably when integer overflows occur would make arithmetic on that platform a lot slower, and would also prevent someone from using a gong wired to the overflow-detect output to let him know he needed to come in from the other room.

Comment: 1) UB makes your code be beyond the standard. That implies your **code** is not compliant anymore. 2) An implementation can do anything. But that is neither allowed nor forbidden by the standard. 2) As you wrote: "... **many** implementations ...". This implies there are some which behave differently. That's exactly why the standard leaves this open. Also note the difference between "implementation defined" and "undefined". The first has to be defined by the implementation and it has to do it the same every time, thus you get the guarantee from the implementation, ...

Comment: Leaving the behavior undefined not only allowed for more efficient code generation but also allowed for the possibility of useful behaviors that might be invented in future, but that doesn't mean the authors of the Standard wouldn't expect that on a machine with 8/16-bit char/int and silent-wraparound two's-complement hardware, something like "unsigned x=uchar1*uchar2;" shouldn't work even when the result is greater than 32767.  To the contrary, the fact that on most then-current implementations the code would work was a motivating factor for having "unsigned char" promote to "signed int".

Comment: ... For the second, the implementation can generate varying results, depending on context, thus emit the optimal code. All this is meant to generate the best code on all platforms. Which is the reason C is one of the fastest HLL. Drawback is you have no safety net and the programmer is expected to know what she is doing.

Comment: You forget that C does not enforce 2's complement encoding. There are very well platforms with 1's complement or sign/magnitude. Btw. UB does not mean your implementation cannot make guarantees on its own. For instance the standard makes conversion from/to function pointer to `void *` UB. But then is exeplicitly mentions it as an extension in J.5.7

Comment: @Olaf: C was designed to be used on a wide variety of platforms.  If integer overflow were Implementation-Defined then platforms where the hardware effect of overflow is unpredictable couldn't effectively process C code.  What should have happened in a lot of cases would have been for the Standard to specify that implementations "should" do certain things *when practical* but allowing for platforms to do otherwise (including behaving unpredictably) if they document that their behavior differs from the commonplace one.

Comment: @Olaf: The term "implementation-defined" requires that implementations document a *particular* behavior, and there are many situations where that may be practical for most implementations but might not be practical for all.  There isn't any category of behavior for which implementations would be required to either specify the range of behaviors that could occur or else *explicitly* state that the program may exhibit arbitrary behavior which does not affect anything that happened previously, arbitrary behavior which could occur "early" but would not disrupt causality, or...

Comment: ...arbitrary behavior which is not bound by laws of time or causality.  For example, given `do {a=slow_function_no_side_effects(a); } while (a & 1); if (a==0) printf("Yielded zero!"); if (a!=0) undefined_behavior();` should the compiler be allowed to print `Yielded zero!` without regard for whether the function ever actually yields an even number, zero or otherwise on the basis that that's the only scenario where behavior would be defined?

Comment: @Olaf: IMHO, the biggest problem with the Standard is that fails to acknowledge the fact that some tasks cannot be efficiently performed without features that can be cheaply supported by many, though not all, implementations.  In 1989, it was sufficient to hand-wave a bit and figure that implementations that could efficiently support features would do so without having to be told, and the fact that some other platforms couldn't support those features wouldn't be an impediment to their support or usability, but that approach is untenable in the presence of aggressive optimizers.

Comment: @Olaf: What's needed is to recognize the concept of a "selectively-conforming" program which specifies via Standard-defined means all of the features that it needs and may optionally waive some guarantees the Standard would normally provide but that it can do without.  Compliant implementations would not be required to support any features beyond the minimal set guaranteed by the Standard, but an implementation that does not support all the features required by a program would be required to report in implementation-defined fashion at least unsupported feature that the program would require.

Comment: @Olaf: Along with that, one could extend the usability of C to smaller embedded platforms by adding the concept of a "selectively-compliant" implementation which may document and impose arbitrary restrictions on the programs it will accept [e.g. forbidding recursive function calls] and reject in Implementation-Defined means any programs not meeting those restrictions, but must behave in compliant fashion for any program it does not reject.  Note that violation of the restrictions could cause a program to be rejected, but could *not* trigger arbitrary Undefined Behavior.

Comment: And still C is used for somewhat exotic platforms as well. You see to think the now widely used 8 bit/byte and unified address pointers without type-encoding, etc. is somewhat natural. You could not be further from the truth. Btw, C leaves a lot to the implementation. That's what _implementation defined behaviour_ means. And - as I already stated - an implementation may very well guarantee a behaviour for otherwise undefined behaviour. But that is not the place nor the time to discuss this

Comment: @Olaf and others. Found some clarification in the latest standard. C11 [link](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html) Annex J, Undefined behaviour: _Conversion between two pointer types produces a result that is incorrectly aligned_ So basically manually aligning pointer is *the only* true way to go in the circumstances. Also, char pointer and void pointer may be the unversal ailiases, but conversion to-and-from does not maintain alingment. Did I understand everything right?

Comment: @Olaf: I've written production C code for a platform with 16-bit `char`, so I'm well aware that such platforms exist if one goes outside the realm of general-purpose reprogrammable microcomputers (in this case, the code was for DSPs).  On the other hand, unless code would be useful on something other than a mass-market general-purpose reprogrammable microcomputer, I don't think there's any benefit to coding it in such a fashion as to use unusual combinations of object sizes.

Comment: @VoidWalker: While it sums up mostly what was stated elsewhere, Annex J is informative only.

Comment: @supercat: DSPs which are/have been in 10s of millions devices are not mass-market? I'd really be interested in where you draw the line. Re the rest: Thee is always a benefit coding standard compliant if that does not add aditional effort==costs. There still is too much rubbish code which could have written compliant without **any** extra effort by e.g. just using the correct definitions (e.g. `stdint.h`, `stddef.h`). It was different with C90 or even K&R, but since 17 years now, there are alternatives. Time to use them.

Comment: @Olaf: I used the phrase "general-purpose reprogrammable microcomputer".  I would consider DSPs to be special-purpose devices, not general-purpose.  How much of a speed penalty should a programmer be willing to accept in exchange for having code that will "probably" run on platforms upon which it's unlikely anyone will want to run it, and how much effort should one expend allowing for every possible platform variation which would be allowable under the Standard, save for the one that cannot be accommodated (there's no requirement that implementations provide enough stack space...

Comment: @supercat: Premature optimisations are the root of evil (not all, though). For general purpose programs (on general purpose CPUs), they are even worse than on special purpose devices. First premise nowadays is to write **readable and maintainable code**. Which includes not relying on implementation defined (or even undefined) behaviour in the first place. It is not so much about running on another platform, but others to understand your code wiothout first learning all nasty details of a specific implementation and target. If you ever fixed such rubbish code, you'll know what I mean.

Comment: ...to do anything other than run at least one possibly-contrived program, nor are implementations required provide any means of determining whether any other program will work reliably).  Further, I would regard so-called "fixed-size" types as being much more conducive to writing genuinely portable if there were a family of unsigned types which would not be promoted to `int`, and one which would always be promoted to a larger signed type.  Presently, implementations can only implement the former for things that are `int`-sized or bigger, and the latter for those that are smaller, but...

Comment: Agreed partly about the problems with coercison to `int`. At lest it should corece to the same signed-ness as the original type. But in practice modern compilers do a lot of magic here already. For instance a compiler for an 8 bit arch can very well use 8 bit operations if it can prove the result is compliant. Just have a look at the assembler code generated. I did ca 15 years ago and was literally baffled how good the code was.

Comment: ...having `uint32_t` behave differently depending upon the size of `int` isn't very helpful.  I repeat my question, though: how much of a speed penalty should programmers be expected to accept writing code which is "100% portable" versus code which would work on any non-obtuse compiler for any machine upon which anyone would want to run it?

Comment: @supercat: To answer that question: as much as he can accept without violating project constraints. Just let the compiler figure out first. If that proves not to be acceptable, **then** optimise by hand. But typically even on small platforms this is often unnecessary with a good compiler (many commercial compilers are way behind, that's why I prefer gcc where available/allowed). This does not mean one can waste resources with a bad overal design, though.

Comment: @Olaf: Over the years, there has been an increasing rift between a low-level language which Dennis Ritchie invented and called C, and a non-low-level subset which confusingly shares the same name.  I recognize that offering compilers freedoms beyond implementing in precise low-level terms will facilitate some automatic optimizations, but only in cases where it doesn't prevent a programmer from exploiting what would otherwise have been a useful feature or guarantee that the platform could have offered at near-zero cost.

Comment: C still is low-level. It just is now much better defined. If you prefer a language that has no well-defined behaviour, you might go with K&R, but dont complain if your company fires you - for good reason. Focus has shifted. But modern embedded software development greatly profits from the standard's definitions. OTOH, I don't consider C a good choice for PC-alike application programming. There's C++ if you want performance (with the option of easy integration of C modules) and true OOP/multi paradigm languages like Python which provide a fully padded environment at the obvious costs.

Comment: @Olaf: In a low-level language, nearly all operations which are UB in the standard would have predictably-constrained behavior *except* in cases where the execution platform itself might jump the rails.  Allowing a compiler to handle various corner cases by choosing among some alternative behaviors in Unspecified fashion, rather than allowing it to jump the rails, may eliminate the need for various kinds of boundary-check code in scenarios where any possible behavior would meet requirements.

Comment: @Olaf: Also, in a low-level language, specifying the memory representation of types will implicitly define the effect of writing to a pointer of one type and reading a pointer of another.  While an implementation might provide optimization *options* which would permit a compiler to reorder memory operations in certain cases, such options would affect whether the compiler's behavior may diverge from program's expressed meaning, but the expressed meaning would continue to be a valid interpretation of the code.

Comment: Low-level languages have no idea of datatypes. Even less about pointers. There are very well aspects I don't like in C. You're welcome to define a true alternative to the C language.

Comment: @Olaf: I'm not sure what you mean, given that I've used assemblers that allow code to define structure types; are those not low-level languages?  In the language Dennis Ritchie invented, the "." and "->" operators were *defined* as accessing an object at a specified displacement from the base.  Given an expression like `foo->bar`, the lvalue `foo` would be used to determine the base address, and in Ritchie's later C variants its type would be used to select the namespace for looking up `bar`, but once `bar` was located and its offset applied, nothing about `foo` mattered.

Comment: @Olaf: In C as defined by Dennis Ritchie, there was no guarantee that a compiler would have to use the same layout for structures that contained things of non-matching types, but if the types and offsets of foo->bar and boz->mum did happen to match (and programmers could, at worst, check for such matching at run-time and abort execution if things that were expected to match, didn't), one could write one and read the other regardless of the underlying structure types; the second major version of the graphics toolbox routines of the Apple Macintosh rely upon that behavior.